# Dojo dstore: both server-side queries and client-side filtering

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm a little confused with how to support both server-side queries and client-side filtering with dstore, and am hoping for some guidance. My scenario:

- I am communicating with an archive server, so I only have get and query requests, nothing that updates the data.
- I want to perform both server-side queries and client-side filtering.
- I'd like to cache the results so I'm not accessing the server for every fetch().

If I use a Request, filter() will pass its query parameters to the server, but the data isn't cached and I can't tell how to filter on the client side.

If I use a RequestMemory, filter() is applied to the local cache, and I can't tell how to specify parameters for the server.

All the pieces seem to be there with dstore, I just haven't figured out how to put them all together yet. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. There were a couple issues with how I was using RequestMemory. The first was that I didn't realize RequestMemory invoked fetch() automatically. The second issue was that I used an object as the queryParam when it should have been an array.

To meet my requirements I created a new store that extended from Request and Cache, just like RequestMemory, but I did not call fetch() in the postscript() function. Then I could pass parameters to the server:

```
store.fetch({queryParams: ['key=value']}).then(function(data) {
  console.log("fetch", data);
});
```

I could then 'freeze' the store by setting `store.isValidFetchCache = true` and subsequently perform client-side filters:

```
store.filter({type: 'xyz'}).fetch().then(function(data) {
  console.log("filter", data);
});
```